# Error while trying to run the command fsck on hadoop

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

i'm working with Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS, trying to go through hadoop quick start
after setting up a name node and a datanode (configured hadoop core-site.xml and hdfs-site.xml),
i'm having an error while running the fsck command

```
'''Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.net.UnknownHostException: master9000
at org.apache.hadoop.security.SecurityUtil.buildTokenService(SecurityUtil.java:445)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.NameNodeProxiesClient.createProxyWithClientProtocol(NameNodeProxiesClient.java:132)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:354)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:288)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.initialize(DistributedFileSystem.java:177)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:3303)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:124)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:3352)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:3320)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:479)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:227)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:463)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:361)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.tools.DFSck.getResolvedPath(DFSck.java:245)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.tools.DFSck.doWork(DFSck.java:331)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.tools.DFSck.access$000(DFSck.java:72)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.tools.DFSck$1.run(DFSck.java:159)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.tools.DFSck$1.run(DFSck.java:156)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1729)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.tools.DFSck.run(DFSck.java:155)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:76)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:90)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.tools.DFSck.main(DFSck.java:402)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: master9000
... 25 more
```

can anyone be of help please ?

Comment: and again with the command hdfs dfsadmin -report
i have the following error

report: java.net.UnknownHostException: master9000

Comment: Typo? You're missing a colon in the address

Comment: the colon is missing when the error was generated, but it's not missing in the core-site.xml file .

<configuration>
 <Property>
  <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
  <value>hdfs://master:9000</value>
 </Property>
</configuration>

Comment: Well, the error seems to think that the colon isn't there